# how to pass custom tag inside another custom tag in angular 2

Tags: angular

Is it possible to pass custom tag inside another custom tag ?

For example

```
<app-component-1>
    <app-component-2>
    </app-component-2>
</app-component-1>
```

because there is code inside app-component-1 is useful many places. where app-component-2 code is not reusable anywhere else.

Or can we pass as property of class? like following

```
<app-component-1 [inside_class] = 'app-component-2'
</app-component-1>
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding an `<ng-content></ng-content>` element to the `<app-component-1>` template.

Then, when you nest something inside `<app-component-1>` like with `<app-component-2>`

```
<app-component-1>
  <app-component-2>
  </app-component-2>
</app-component-1>
```

The nested content will be rendered instead of (i.e. inside) of the `<ng-content></ng-content>` tags

**Note**: by default, `<ng-content>` will render everything nested within it's parent element. You can also pass a `selector=""` option to `<ng-content>`if you only want to render elements matching a specific css selector that are nested within the parent element (<-- potentially confusing sentence)